# Mule - where to place a file so that it can be read by Mule Studio and Mule Standalone?

Tags: mule, filepath, mule-studio

I have a Mule flow that is performing an XSLT transformation, and I've placed my XSL stylesheet in `src/main/resources/`. When I package my application and deploy it to an instance of Mule Standalone, deployment of the app fails with the error:

```
org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: IOException: Unable to load resource src/main/resources/transform.xsl
```

Is there a location I can place my file in that can be used mutually by Mule Studio and Mule Standalone? Or a way of creating a dynamic path to the XSL file so that I don't have this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the configuration xml where you are using this xslt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use it the following way.

```
xsl-file="transform.xsl"    instead of   xsl-file="src/main/resources/transform.xsl"
```

Hope this helps.